# smart double quotes cause compilation error

Tags: java

I am facing a error in Java using the method Loops. I  am a basic user learning Java and I am following a book with teaches you the basics of Java.

I have this problem when I use this code in my Java Program. It gives me an red line under my code. Here's my code:

```
public class Game{

    public static void main(String[] args){

    for (int dex = 0; dex < 1000; dex++) {
    if (dex % 12 == 0) {
          System.out.println(“#: “ + dex);
        }
       }
     }
    }
```

I have been following the tutorials correctly. I am a bit lost where I have gone or done wrong. I have my public static codes and such as you'd require in any Java programming.

**Here's are the error given):**

```
Cannot resolve method: 'Println(? , ?)'
Expression expected
',' or ')' expected
Unexpected Token
';' expected
```

Comment: What exactly is the problem? Are you getting any errors? If, yes, please add the error in your question too.

Comment: Hi! I get red lines under my code. I don't understand where I've gone wrong. :-) I've updated my question witch should help you give you a better understanding of my problem!

Comment: Ok, if you hover over the code underlined in red, it wil show you an error. Please add that error here.

Comment: I'll add the error's on the article! :-) Please give me a mintue or two.

Comment: The error message seems to say that your actually used System.out.Println instead of System.out.println. In Java, always respect the conventions about classes, variables, and methods name case to avoid this kind of problems.

Comment: What *editor* are you using to write Java code? Are you using an IDE like Eclipse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code compiles and runs without problems on my computer. I only had to replace your “ by "

```
 public class Game{

    public static void main(String[] args){

      for (int dex = 0; dex < 1000; dex++) {
        if (dex % 12 == 0) {
          System.out.println("#: " + dex);
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

Comment: Could be the smart quotes in the question that caused it?

Comment: these smart quotes are not used in normal editors but used only in proprietary editors like in ms office. So they need not to be understood by javac.

Answer (score 0):

nothing is wrong here with the code but use valid double quotes as java reads. Your code is not using them. As

System.out.println("#: " + dex);